# Build form inside show action for outside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms

I am trying to build a form inside the show action of a controller. Here is my setup.

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

   # Associations 
   has_many :feeds
   has_many :subscriptions

  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions

end
```

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Associations
    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :feed

end
```

Using a Subscription namespace:

```
  # Subscriptions
  namespace :subscriptions do
    resources :categories
  end
```

Inside the show action for a category (http://URL.com/subscriptions/categories/1), I want to build the subscriptions model form and list the available feeds for that category. I want the form to submit the checked off feeds to the Subscription model.

CategoriesController

```
  def show
    @feeds = Feed.where("category_id = ?", @category)
  end
```

Trying to build the form in the Show action of the Categories view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:subscriptions, @category] do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :feeds, collection: @feeds, value_method: :id, as: :check_boxes %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Right now it is rendering the appropriate information, but it is rendering as an edit form, not a create form. How do I fix this?

What else do I need to add to my routes / controller to actually get the information to save to the Subscription model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing i am not sure where you initialize the  @category object in show action and in view. if you want to render a new page than it should be map to new action of the controller and you path with will be

```
http://URL.com/subscriptions/categories/new
```

the path you are using

```
http://URL.com/subscriptions/categories/1
```

will always map to the show action according to rails convention though you can override that for you accordingly but that is not a good practice. also in new action initialize the instance by

```
@category = Category.new
```

now on submit it will automatically goes to the create action. if your @category is already persisted in the database for example

```
 @category = Category.find(1)
```

now if this object goes to the simple_form_for it will send the data to update action .